# How does a trailing closure work?

Tags: swift

I read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) one but did not get anything understandable for me. But I understand this closures syntax:

```
var cal = {(num1: Int)-> Int in
    return num1 * 2;
}

var clusers = [cal,
               {(num1:Int) -> Int in return num1 * 3},
               {(num1:Int) -> Int in num1 * 4},
               {(num1:Int) in num1 * 5},
               { num1 in num1 * 6},
               { $0 * 7}]
for cluser in clusers{
    cluser(100)
}
```

How can I make a trailing closure ?

Basically here is a trailing closure. I am unable to understand that:

```
  //call dispatch async to send a closure to download queue
  dispatch_async(download) { () ->Void in

    //some code goes here          
  }
```

Comment: check this video https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/intermediate-swift-3/lessons/2 couple other links for more info https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-trailing-closure-syntax/ and https://www.quora.com/Apple-Swift-programming-language-What-is-a-trailing-closure

Comment: This is also a really good resource https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/

Comment: @AK1 thanks  i got it

Answer (score 1):

Let this is my function

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(index: Int, closure: () -> Void) {

}
```

If you need to pass a closure to the above function you write something like below

```
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(5, closure: {
   // code included in closure
})
```

But if closure is the last argument passed to the function, as in the above function we can write above piece of code like this also

```
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(5) { 
   // code included in closure
}
```

That is why it is called trailing closure.